# Can the SAM database be encrypted with EFS to prevent offline password cracking?

Tags: windows, security, encryption, efs

Is it possible to EFS-encrypt the SAM database to prevent offline password cracking?

Would it have to be encrypted as the `SYSTEM` user?

Comment: Sounds like a surefire way to destroy Windows. :D I shall try with a VM later.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Password cracking is never required in the first place.  All you need is the hash to wreak havoc.  See this:  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/168940/what-harm-is-there-in-obtaining-password-hashes-in-a-windows-environment/168941#168941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it’s simply not possible:

[image: asdf]

If you were to encrypt the file while Windows is not running, it would not use the correct EFS certificate, which will most likely break Windows.

Comment: Nice investigation. Also note that even if the effort was successful, nothing would have been accomplished security-wise. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks for checking out. I guess Bitlocker is the only way to secure it ultimately then?

Answer (score 3):

You probably can't, and even if you could, it wouldn't do any good.

The `SAM` file is always in use, and you can't even close the handles to it with Process Explorer running as `SYSTEM`. Therefore, `cipher` fails with an access-denied error.

If you encrypted the file with a normal user's key, Windows wouldn't be able to access it (because it needs your password to unlock your key), and the boot process would fail.

You could conceivably export `SYSTEM`'s key to another machine, mount the target machine's hard drive there, and encrypt the offline `SAM` file with it. That has a high chance of breaking Windows, because the Security Accounts Manager service (`SamSs`) claims to be really important to the start of all other services:

> The startup of this service signals other services that the Security Accounts Manager (SAM) is ready to accept requests.  Disabling this service will prevent other services in the system from being notified when the SAM is ready, which may in turn cause those services to fail to start correctly. This service should not be disabled.

The Encrypting File System service (`EFS`), though it doesn't explicitly depend on the SAM, does have some concept of accounts because it maps keys to users. EFS [does have a kernel-mode driver](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb457116.aspx#EJAA), and it runs in the same process as the SAM (`lsass.exe`), so it could conceivably start before the `SAM` file is needed, but fiddling around with such low-level parts of the OS is probably a dubious plan.

If you somehow succeeded, you wouldn't have accomplished anything. The computer has to be able to get `SYSTEM`'s EFS key without you entering any password, and so it has to be stored unencrypted on disk. Therefore, the attacker would just grab `SYSTEM`'s private key, wherever it is, use it to decrypt `SAM`, and then proceed to do anything desired with the data inside.

Comment: You're right that it wouldn't do any good.  Take a look at this:  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/168940/what-harm-is-there-in-obtaining-password-hashes-in-a-windows-environment/168941#168941

Answer (score 2):

- It is not possible to encrypt the SAM database using EFS.
- But it is possible to encrypt the SAM database

The feature has existed in Windows since Windows NT 4.0 (1996): [**SysKey**.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994564(v=ws.10).aspx) [*(archive)*](http://archive.is/5zrW7)

From a command prompt run:

```
>syskey.exe
```

and the UI will appear:

[image]

Be aware that it's a one-way operation.

- you will have to type in the password every time you boot
- you cannot remove the encryption of the SAM database

### Update 2017 - SysKey removed from Windows 10

Starting with Windows 10 version 1709, SysKey will no longer be included. From [KB4025993](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4025993/syskey-exe-utility-is-no-longer-supported-in-windows-10-version-1709)

> ### Syskey.exe utility is no longer supported in Windows 10 version 1709 and Windows Server version 1709
>
> The syskey.exe utility and its underlying support in the Windows OS was first introduced in Windows 2000 and backported to Windows NT 4.0.
>
> Unfortunately, the syskey encryption key and the use of syskey.exe are no longer considered secure. Syskey is based on weak cryptography that can easily be broken in modern times. The data that is protected by syskey is very limited and does not cover all files or data on the OS volume. The syskey.exe utility has also been known to be used by hackers as part of ransomware scams.

As they note; you're better off using something like BitLocker, or VeraCrypt for the tin-foil people.